# Event handlers with non-framework single page applications

Tags: javascript, routes

I've been toying with single page applications using JS routers but *without* full front-end frameworks like Angular or React. A lot of the sites I work on are small, utility sites, so a full framework often adds work rather than reduces.

I've found several router libraries that work well but I can't seem to work my head around how to listen for and adjust event listeners on elements rendered by the router rather than loaded by the window (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764123/event-binding-with-router) for more details).

The only solution that *kind* of works is to use event delegation on a parent already present in the root document or to use `.on()` with jQuery, but I'm not a huge fan of jQuery in general.

Are there other mechanisms I could be using to dynamically add event listeners on templates displayed by a router?